# On-the-fly SMB shares conf to quickly share files

Tags: permissions, samba, smb, shared-folders

I want to use samba to quickly and easily share files on occasions. I set up a smbuser to which I forbid login with

```
chsh -s /bin/false smbuser
```

I give the smbuser's password to people and I have my home dir with another username I keep safe.

Let's suppose I have this folder /home/steve/pictures/vacation/... I want to share.

With a quick chown steve:smbuser vacation I can set the following permissions

```
drwxr----- 35 steve smbuser  4096 Mar 28 18:58  vacation
```

then I set this service on my smb.conf

```
[shared]
        comment = Used to share files quickly. Just change path down here
        path = /home/steve/pictures/vacation
        browsable = yes
        read only = yes
        create mask = 0700
        directory mask = 0700
        valid user = smbuser
```

with this configuration I cannot connect to this share.

If I

```
chmod -R 777 /home/steve
```

I can connect, but this is not the way.

How can I configure this in a better way?

Answer (score 1):

The Samba fileserver really just follows the Unix file permissions; if you log in as `smbuser` to SMB, you get the permissions of the Unix account `smbuser` as well.

Of course, your `chmod -R 0777` is complete overkill because you probably don't want everyone to have full write rights to your home directory, but the answer is still that you need to perform *some* kind of `chmod`.

- On all parent directories, you **need to grant `+x`** to allow other users to traverse them (i.e. access objects within):

  ```
  chmod a+x /home/steve
  chmod a+x /home/steve/pictures
  ```
- On the directories being shared, you need to grant **`+rx`** so that users could list the files as well as actually access them (as well as `+r` on the files themselves, for hopefully obvious reasons):

  ```
  chmod -R g+rX /home/steve/pictures/vacation
  ```

  (The uppercase `+X` means "only grant +x to directories, and to files that already have +x for someone".)

Comment: This was useful but in the end I decided to go for 'net usershare' command. Way more handy and cool.
Look at [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/742516/on-the-fly-smb-shares-conf-to-quickly-share-files) for more info